# When creating a c# console application, should classes be created that run/manage the execution of the application?

Tags: c#, class, oop

I've been trying to get my head around OOP for around two years now and still don't understand a whole bunch of aspects, this being one of them.

I'm trying to create a personal nutrition console app that stores a database of food items and their nutritional info, which a user can use to total their daily intake of calories and protein.

I have created classes for elements such as "User", "UserList", "FoodItem", "LiquidItem", "FoodDatabase" etc.

But one element that confuses me and has on my previous projects, is do I create classes that deal with the actual running of the application?

For example, would I have classes such as "WelcomeUser", from which a user can choose what to do?

In my previous application, a TicTacToe game, I had classes such as "StartGame", "TakeTurn". "RulesDisplay", and don't know whether these state based elements should be put into their own classes.

Apologies if this question is a bit vague, but I hope to elaborate if anybody can catch my train of thought. Any insight is much appreciated.

Cheers everyone!

Comment: The question may be pretty much opinion based, I think. From my viewpoint it's fair to model certain stuff like states in classes. There are certain software patterns like the state or strategy pattern that utilize this. Nonetheless, I'd recommend to name those classes with nouns, like `IdleState` or `TakingTurnState` whatsoever. Either way, it's hard to answer the question IMO because it's a design decision.

Comment: @Peit is correct...this is somehow one opinion. Dispite that, typically I tend to have classes for entities and classes for business on those entities. For example, if I have an entity "Player", I have the respective possible actions in another class (PlayerBE and PlayerBS), where BE - Business Entity and BS - Business Service). Then it has everything to do with the purpose of what we are building and what is the best pattern/design to apply (or patterns). Dependency Injection, Dependency Revertion, Observable Parent, etc...
which, in turn, will always give rise to new classes...

Comment: Typically classes are nouns, so "StartGame" and "TakeTurn" don't sound like good choices for classes. They sound more like methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Peit and RicardoRodrigues.  So to clarify, once I've established classes such as "TurnState", "WelcomePlayers", "RunRulesDisplay", would I simply run all of these within the Main method of my application's "Program" class, and use loops/other states with conditional evaluations (methods) within these methods to decide when to switch from state class to state class?  Once again thanks for your rapid replies, it's very much appreciated and reassuring.

Comment: @k314159 I have been studying further into OOP and read about the practice of having classes as nouns. So in this path of thinking, where and through what classes would I manage the actual running of the application? Surely I wouldn't just list everything in the "Main" method directly with loops directly implemented into "Main"? This seems messy, but again I'm a complete beginner and very open to the idea that I'm completely wrong.

Comment: I would create methods that I call from Main. And classes to help with those methods, for example things like "GameState" to hold the positions of the Xs and Os.